# Animate elements position not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, dragula

I'm trying to implement a grid which you can drag 'n drap elements. I found [dragula](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula), which suits my needs exactly! The only thing is, I need the tiles to animate when they move out of the way to let in the one being dragged. (Hope that's clear. :))

I tried adding a `transition: all 1s ease-out`, but all that did, was animated the opacity.

How can I animate the change of positions?

#### JSFiddle

```js
dragula([document.getElementById('left-rm-spill')]);
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container * {
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bevacqua/dragula/master/dist/dragula.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bevacqua/dragula/master/dist/dragula.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="left-rm-spill" class="container">
  <div>Anxious Cab Driver</div>
  <div>Thriving Venture</div>
  <div>Such <a href="http://ponyfoo.com">a good blog</a>
  </div>
  <div>Calm Clam</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Urka3.gif the kind of animation you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @AleksanderAzizi Exactly!

Comment: It seems this kind of animation isn't supported with dragula. I'd suggest creating your own drag and drop with HTML5, using your own animation.

Comment: That's too advanced for me. I wanted to, but realized I couldn't. If I would have some help, I'd probably be able to pull it off.